# Add spacing between two rows in a table not working in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, css-tables

I've a table on where I need a spacing between two rows `<tr>` of table. I did it in following way:

```
table.fltrTbl
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:0 11px;  
}

table.fltrTbl td
{ 
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-right:14px; 
    padding-left:0;
    padding-top:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
    margin:0;
}

table.fltrTbl tr
{ 
}
```

But, this solution is not working with IE7. Can you suggest any changes to this class in order to make that work in IE7?

Note: Please do not answer apply separate class to every tr in table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the border-spacing, change border-collapse to collapse and just use the td padding to create the spacing.

Comment: Unfortunately, padding doesn't work well with vertical-align:middle

Answer (score 3):

IE7 doesn't support `border-spacing` at all. (And IE 8 only with one value). For IE7 you can use the HTML attribute `cellspacing` instead - but also only with one value for both horizontal and vertical spacing.

The only cross browser way to have a horizontal gap in table is to use a blank table row and cell.

Comment: that is wrong, this works in IE7. `*border-collapse: expression('separate', cellSpacing = '5px');`

Comment: what IE7 documentation? Why not just run that in IE7 and see if it works? I know it does work by: 1. Prepending the star (*) before the statement (a widely known hack for IE7) and 2. Applying an expression ( the way MS likes things done). I could be more verbose .....

Comment: @Nepaluz I assumed that it worked, but what interests me, was `cellSpacing = '5px'` as the second argument, which according to MSDN would normally be a string determining the scripting language, which it obviously isn't. Why does a variable assignment work there, and why does it apply to the selected element?

Comment: you were right to assume it works (I have tried it). I think the evaluation of the expression works differently in hack-mode; in any case, '5px' in my book is a string, consider `*border-collapse: expression('separate', cellSpacing = 5);` and if you have the time, run that too.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the desired effect using `border: 2px solid transparent` only for ie7 (you can use the condicional comments to apply this style only to ie7).

In the example given I added a 2px transparent border all around the td, but it might be the values you want, and it works for specific borders such as `border-left` or `border-bottom`.

Answer (score 1):

For me changing the [border-collapse property](http://w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_border-collapse.asp) to `border-collapse: separate` on the `td` element is what worked. According to the W3C, when using `collapse` *border-spacing and empty-cells properties will be ignored*. When using `separate` border-spacing properties are honored, and that is what we want.

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix via expression:

```
*border-collapse: expression('separate', cellSpacing = '5px');
```

Answer (score 0):

To add spacing to my menu items I used a padding-bottom attribute in my css.

```
<style>
div.c4 {
           font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
           font-size: 12px;
           font-weight: bold;
           text-align: left;
           color: #800000;
           padding-bottom: .5em;
        }
</style
```

The HTML:

```
<table width="15%" style="margin: auto;" >
<tr>
<th scope="col">
<div class="c4">Home</div>
<div class="c4">About Me</div>
<div class="c4">Photographs</div>
<div class="c4">Locations</div>
<div class="c4">Testimonials</div>
</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

here is my jsfiddle example:
    http://jsfiddle.net/IConway/htsqoe7j/